# Usage of the maven-shade plugin's AppenderTransformer

Tags: spring, maven

Okay, I am running into the typical problem in which I need to create a uber jar, but my project dependencies has multiple spring.handlers and spring.schemas files. I have search around and figured out that my problem required me to use the maven-shade plugin, along with it's AppendingTransformer. The problem is that when I add the configuration and run the goal it does not merge the files; what's more, I can put a bogus classpath in for the appender or resource file and it does not complain, which lead me to believe that it is not even attempting to execute the transformer.

execute- mvn compile package shade:shade

```
    <build>
    <finalName>mongo-dictionary</finalName>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration> 
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

where is this plugin configuration, can you ensure that it is in the right place - build -> plugins  element of the project for which you are creating uber jar. I have the same configuration which works for me.

Also you don't need to execute shade:shade separately. Running mvn package will do that for you.

Comment: So here is the entire build portion of my pom.xml

Comment: I have added the entire build section. Please review and let me know if there is any issues

Comment: I had my plugins configured as children of the pluginManagement element, once I got rid of the pluginManagement tage everything works as advertised. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

I had my plugins configured as children of the pluginManagement element, once I got rid of the pluginManagement tag everything works as advertised.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - please add a working example, showing what was changed (if possible).